# sbt task failed when add spark dependencies

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm new to spark and Scala. I encountered a problem when following a tutorial of setting up scala/spark in Intellij Idea.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tDL1.png) When I add the line: libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.5" to the file build.sbt, there is always an error. The returned information shows that "sbt task failed" and "Extracting structure failed". I have tried different spark visions but get the same result. How can I solve this problem?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwhbW.png)

Comment: Spark doesn't support Scala `2.13` you need to downgrade your Scala version to `2.12`

Comment: Thank you very much. This works for me